# Basic CLI BlackJack Game in Java

Tags: java, game, console

I am looking to see which aspects of this code could use improvement.

In both design, and basic implementation and coding.

I'm using *[IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)* and *[Java SE 20](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk20-archive-downloads.html)*.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlackJack blackJack = new BlackJack();
        blackJack.round();
    }

    List<Character> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Character> iterator;

    BlackJack() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
            cards.addAll(List.of('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K'));
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    void round() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        iterator = cards.iterator();
        int score = 0, dealerScore = 0;
        int card;
        String string;
        boolean exit = false, exitAce;
        do {
            System.out.print("hit / stand:  ");
            string = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            switch (string) {
                case "hit" -> {
                    if ((card = draw()) != 1) {
                        score += card;
                        System.out.printf("hit +%d, score %d%n", card, score);
                    } else {
                        do {
                            System.out.print("ace, 1 or 11:  ");
                            string = scanner.nextLine();
                            exitAce = true;
                            if (!string.matches("11?")) {
                                System.out.println("invalid input, try again");
                                exitAce = false;
                            } else {
                                if (string.equals("1")) score += 1;
                                else if (string.equals("11")) score += 11;
                                System.out.printf("hit +%s, score %d%n", string, score);
                            }
                        } while (!exitAce);
                    }
                }
                case "stand" -> { }
                case "" -> exit = true;
                default -> System.out.println("invalid input, try again");
            }
            if (!exit) {
                if (score == 21) {
                    System.out.println("21, you win");
                    exit = true;
                } else if (score > 21) {
                    System.out.println("you've bust, dealer wins");
                    exit = true;
                } else {
                    dealerScore += card = draw();
                    System.out.printf("dealer hit +%d, score %d%n", card, dealerScore);
                    if (dealerScore == 21) {
                        System.out.println("dealer 21, you loose");
                    } else if (dealerScore > 21) {
                        System.out.println("dealer busts, you win");
                        exit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (!exit);
    }

    int draw() {
        char card;
        return switch (card = iterator.next()) {
            case 'A' -> 1;
            case 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T' -> 10;
            default -> Character.digit(card, 10);
        };
    }
}
```

Here are a few input and outputs.

```
hit / stand:  hit
hit +4, score 4
dealer hit +4, score 4
hit / stand:  hit
hit +10, score 14
dealer hit +4, score 8
hit / stand:  stand
dealer hit +10, score 18
hit / stand:  hit
hit +6, score 20
dealer hit +4, score 22
dealer busts, you win
```

```
hit / stand:  hit
hit +6, score 6
dealer hit +10, score 10
hit / stand:  hit
hit +10, score 16
dealer hit +4, score 14
hit / stand:  hit
hit +6, score 22
you've bust, dealer wins
```

```
hit / stand:  hit
hit +10, score 10
dealer hit +10, score 10
hit / stand:  hit
ace, 1 or 11:  11
hit +11, score 21
21, you win
```

Answer (score 2):

### you should apply [IOSP](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP) ans [SLAP](https://Single%20Level%20of%20Abstraction%20(SLA))

instead of having one big method, where you do calculation and flow control split this big method (`void round()`) into smaller sub-method (IOSP)

that makes your code more easy to read (SLAP) - because you can see on top level whats going on

```
do {
    handlePlayer();
    handleDealer();
}while(!exit);
```

IOSP can be applied on many levels of your code

### think in objects, abjure [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession)

it is not so hard to create a class for your cards, or at least an enum for cards. that would clean up the code on some levels. Especially the values of the cards would then have a proper place to live.

and these statement would be cleared up
`(card = draw()) != 1)` --> `(card = draw()).isAce())`

### tripping hazard (lack of cohesion)

why is the initialition of your `iterator` somewhere in the code? it should be inside the init method - it took me some time to find it.

```
void init() {
    for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++){ //java code style requires ALWAYS bracket on for & if
        cards.addAll(List.of('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K'));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    iterator = cards.iterator(); //misssed it on this place!
}
```

### minor issue: Nespresso - What else

avoid else statementens. they bloat up your code and increase complexity in an unnecessary way.

```
if (score == 21) {
    System.out.println("21, you win");
    break; 
} //no else here

if (score > 21) {
    System.out.println("you've bust, dealer wins");
    break;
} //no else here, too
```

this issue is not so important and can be skipped.

Comment: _avoid else statement[s]_ is not useful advice either generally or in this specific case. The second case can only be true if the first case is false, so an `else` (1) increases natural legibility and (2), if interpreted literally by a compiler, offers an optimization path in the form of short circuiting.

Comment: Thanks for the review.  The reason I'm not using the _break_ keyword is because I wanted to avoid early-returns.  If I ever _do_ utilize an early-return it's typically when I'm re-assigning a local value, thus subsequent code should be skipped.  It's specific to design, I guess.  As for the last recommendation, in terms of the brackets, that is not true, my code runs fine without the brackets there.  And, for the _iterator_, I was going for a lazy-instantiation.  In the event that _round_ was called more than once.  Now that I look at it, I guess I should also re-shuffle the cards.

Comment: honestly the improved if/else findings are low prio - if the OP could apply IOSP / SLAP & get rid of Primitive Obsession then that would be sufficient and alreadyx improve the code greatly @Reilas

Comment: i will adjust my answer according to your both feedback @Reinderien